# How to import java's @Plugin annotation?

Tags: java

I am attempting to use the `@Plugin` annotation. Am following the example of FileAppender [here](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/FileAppender.java).

However, java does not recognize it and instead I get

```
error: package org.apache.logging.log4j.plugins does not exist
```

Is there some jar I need to include? I already have the log4j jars `log4j-api-2.14.0.jar` and `log4j-core-2.14.0.jar` (as well as `log4j-slf4j18-impl-2.14.0.jar`).

How do I get the import working in order to use `@Plugin`?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the import line was different than it was for all the example code I was referencing.

I searched within the jar to check whether any `Plugin` classes were there, and noticed they had a different path than the import line in the examples.

```
> jar -tf .\log4j-core-2.14.0.jar | rg Plugin
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/util/PluginRegistry$PluginTest.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/util/PluginManager.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/visitors/PluginAttributeVisitor.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/processor/PluginProcessor$PluginAliasesElementVisitor.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/processor/PluginCache.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/util/PluginBuilder.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/PluginBuilderAttribute.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/visitors/PluginElementVisitor.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/PropertiesPlugin.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/processor/PluginProcessor$1.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/visitors/PluginConfigurationVisitor.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/processor/PluginEntry.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/visitors/PluginBuilderAttributeVisitor.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/visitors/AbstractPluginVisitor.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/processor/PluginProcessor$PluginElementVisitor.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/PluginNode.class
META-INF/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/Log4j2Plugins.dat
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/visitors/PluginVisitor.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/PluginAttribute.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/PluginValue.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/FailoversPlugin.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/PluginBuilderFactory.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/util/PluginType.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/util/PluginRegistry.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/Plugin.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/PluginAliases.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/PluginVisitorStrategy.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/AppendersPlugin.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/visitors/PluginVisitors.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/LoggersPlugin.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/visitors/PluginValueVisitor.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/visitors/PluginNodeVisitor.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/processor/PluginProcessor.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/PluginConfiguration.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/PluginFactory.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/PluginElement.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/ScriptsPlugin.class
```

I changed the import line from

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.plugins.Plugin;
```

to

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.Plugin;
```

and then the annotations were recognized.